# Dynamics CRM - Open entity form on ribbon button click

Tags: ribbon, microsoft-dynamics

I'm planning to add a ribbon button to an existing group for a specific entity. I have created a custom entity, which is a child of the entity for which I'm creating the ribbon button. How do I open the new custom entity form on click of this ribbon button from the parent entity's screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution to the problem stated above is:
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/archive/2013/01/31/supported-ways-of-accessing-url-addressable-forms-reports-scripts.aspx#.UU6ZydazRVo